# Why doesn't Swashbuckle find my classes?

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

[Can I automate documenting an existing REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796686) was a great start and now I have all of my API methods documented.  But I am not seeing class documentation from markup like:

```
public class Group : IGroup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Group ID
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }
```

My solution has classes defined in one project and the API controllers in another.  I've added Swashbuckle to the project which defines the classes and turned on XML documentation in the build but I don't see the `<summary>` comments from my class in the Swagger output.  What am I missing?

Comment: Worth posting your swagger configuration (EnableSwagger and similar calls).

Comment: I kind of expected this to just work but perhaps                      `c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yep and make sure you enable it in your build options